# Synonym request: [pos-tagger] -> [pos-tagging]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

A part-of-speech tagger performs part-of-speech tagging.  It is hard to imagine a scenario where a tagger would be used for anything unrelated to tagging, so I suggest we should get rid of the [pos-tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pos-tagger) and make it a synonym of [pos-tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pos-tagging).

Note that the [pos-tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pos-tagger) has more questions and a better tag wiki, so we should attempt to reach a consensus to merge the tag wikis before completely getting rid of this tag.

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputation in either of these tags to propose an actual [synonym](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pos-tagger/synonyms)